# Layout stylings doesn't show up on samsung

Tags: android, android-layout

I've recently published my first app on play store. I was testing it with many brands like one plus,huawei,sony,lg etc. and there was no problem. However when I open the app with Samsung smartphones the layout sytlings are not there and it is only happening one page. Is there any specification I need to do for certain brand or problem is about my code? 
CodePen link for activity is in the comment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:id="@+id/Linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Linear2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin"
        android:textColor="#4fa5d5"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview123"
        tools:ignore="UnknownId"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativee">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewasd"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin"
        android:textColor="#4fa5d5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewasd"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"

        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewasd1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewasd"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#4fa5d5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewasd1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewasd2"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewasd1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#4fa5d5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewasd2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text2"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewasd3"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewasd2"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#4fa5d5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewasd3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text3"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/divider"
        android:id="@+id/textViewasd4"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/divider"
        android:id="@+id/textViewasd5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewasd4"
        android:fontFamily="@font/berlin"
        android:text="%5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#4fa5d5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Lordberbeross/post/layout

Comment: what specific styles are missing?

Comment: all Samsung mobiles? OS?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot for samsung device and other brand device?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/klILrLk I've tried with several samsung mobiles. It looks like this. But it supposed to be like this https://imgur.com/a/RufPiAD. First one with samsung, second one with one plus.

Comment: I think your problem is only for screen device issue because as far i see in the screenshots. the samsung device is the most wide length in terms of height. So maybe you should try to examine again the layout in this article  https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: I guess the problem is not about samsung devices it's about screen density. Try changing your fixed width/heigth values. That should work.

Comment: Even when I change the fixed width, positioning is getting better but not fontstyle. I

Answer (score 0):

And also try this `implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'` it works for me to used this for text in my android app. It will appear same size in different device(sizes). Just implement this in  `android:textSize=""` according to your textSize you want.

sample code

```
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_input"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_input_background"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:textColorHint="#434343"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
```